# Serial Port Fails to open, Error 2?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I'm having problems with opening a serial port in C++ on Windows 7. I'd like to send serial data from my computer to another one through a USB cable. The code I've found from various online sources is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Define the five bytes to send ("hello")
    char bytes_to_send[5];
    bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
    bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
    bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[4] = 111;

    // Declare variables and structures
    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};

    // Open the highest available serial port number
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");
    hSerial = CreateFile(
                "COM8", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
                OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0 );
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            printf ("CreateFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");
```

The programme never gets past this point, and the error which it throws is "Error 2". From what I've read I think this corresponds to "**System cannot find the file specified**". However it won't open for whatever COM port I try to use. I've also tried "\\.\COM8" but to no avail. Does anyone know some common problems that could be causing this issue? Are there any hardware specific issues to look out for?

Comment: Silly question, I know: Do you actually have a COM8?

Comment: It's a fair question, I know that the COM list on my computer goes up to at least 20 from previous experience. But I've never tried accessing any COM port in this way before.

Comment: Do you see COM8 listed in Device Manager?

Comment: `"COM8"` rarely works, too many crappy drivers around, `"\\\\.\\COM8"` should be your next try.  Backslashes need to be escaped.

Comment: I don't know  how to get the COM port to appear in Device manager. How I would like to test the programme is by sending serial data to another computer. Is there a specific way I should be setting this up? Thanks